# Converting date from english to spanish on an email template

Tags: language, conversion

I have a email template that contains date/time spell out like "Wednesday 6/17/2015". When Spanish is the preferred language, how do i convert the date into spanish??

```
  Hi {{my.Account Name_Oppty:default=Sunrun Homeowner}}, 
  We hope you are as excited as we are to get going on the design of your system! As a next step, 
  we’ll be sending a site auditor to your home to gather details about your roof and electric panel - 
  this enables us to customize a system that’s unique to your home. 
  Your site audit is scheduled for {{my.Site Audit Date Time_Oppty}}, 
  and will take about two hours. 
  We will need you to be there during the audit, so we’ll call you to confirm a day before.
```

Comment: please show your email template fragment where you format the date (datetime) field

Comment: Hi {{my.Account Name_Oppty:default=Sunrun Homeowner}},
We hope you are as excited as we are to get going on the design of your system! As a next step, we’ll be sending a site auditor to your home to gather details about your roof and electric panel - this enables us to customize a system that’s unique to your home. Your site audit is scheduled for {{my.Site Audit Date Time_Oppty}}, and will take about two hours. We will need you to be there during the audit, so we’ll call you to
confirm a day before.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML email templates, the locale of the user sending the template determines the format of the merge fields.  The picklist is available on the user record.

Now you mentioned translate as well, if you meant translate the text, my experience with validation rules leads me to believe that you would need to use custom labels and the workbench.  Even though I haven't used it, to translate with visualforce templates, use the  tag's language attribute.